# unable to use not_if in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to implement not_if when using a bash attribute

**I am trying to start the WAS Deployment manager but only if its not running, i am using a simple grep command to get the pid of the process which is wokring as you can see in the log below**

```
#Start the DMGR process
bash "start-dmgr" do
  user "root"
  code %(#{node[:websphere][:was][:was_installLocation]}/bin/startManager.sh)
  not_if ("ps -f|grep dmgr|grep -v grep| awk {'print $2'}")
end
```

Below are the debug logs from chef client

**When the DMGR process is **running****

```
[2013-06-07T15:13:54-04:00] DEBUG: Skipping bash[was-install-fixpacks] due to not_if command `/apps/websphere/ws70/bin/versionInfo.sh -maintenancePackages | grep `echo /mnt/newInstallers/WAS/APARs/7.0.0.19-WS-WAS-IFPM73674.pak | awk -F '-' '{print $4}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'``
Recipe: WAS_NPE::was_startdmgr
  * bash[start-dmgr] action run[2013-06-07T15:13:54-04:00] INFO: Processing bash[start-dmgr] action run (WAS_NPE::was_startdmgr line 2)
1973
 (skipped due to not_if)
```

**When the DMGR process is **NOT running****

```
[2013-06-07T15:31:03-04:00] DEBUG: Skipping bash[was-install-fixpacks] due to not_if command `/apps/websphere/ws70/bin/versionInfo.sh -maintenancePackages | grep `echo /mnt/newInstallers/WAS/APARs/7.0.0.19-WS-WAS-IFPM73674.pak | awk -F '-' '{print $4}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'``
Recipe: WAS_NPE::was_startdmgr
  * bash[start-dmgr] action run[2013-06-07T15:31:03-04:00] INFO: Processing bash[start-dmgr] action run (WAS_NPE::was_startdmgr line 2)
 (skipped due to not_if)
```

**No matter what the case its always skipping, what is that i am missing out**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RTM: https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html

The resource is executed when **not_if** block returns *false*. In bash world *false* means that the exit code of bash script is not 0.

Make sure your bash script exits with different exit codes. You may try it without awk:

```
ps -f | grep -v grep | grep dmgr
```

Because grep exits with 1, when no match is found.

Comment: Thankyou Draco, it works like a charm. The explanation was wonderful. thanks again.

Comment: I come from programming languages where 1 is true so wrapping my head around 0 being true and anything but 0 being false for shell is REALLY driving me nuts.

Comment: It is very dependant on language. In ruby, for example, any number is true, including 0.

Comment: It never fails... when someone says "RTM", the link always 404s :)